# HTML5 Cache Size?

Tags: ipad, caching, html

I'm looking into creating an Web or iPad application that will use HTML5. After some research I've discovered that HTML5 has Database caching, and was wondering how large that cache is?

I'd be looking to provide an offline solution so the users can still fill out forms, and pull information from the database if they're out in the field and cannot obtain a 3G signal. The database caching would be fairly large ( a couple tables with thousands of records each ), and would have re-cache weekly.

Is there a limitation to how much data HTML5 can cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't been able to find anything regarding a hard size limitation or any indications of a size limit through searching any HTML documentation.

I believe that Safari has a 5MB cap on application storage for iPhone / iPad (*You had mentioned using an iPad.*)

[Here is the HTML Standard regarding Offline Web Application's / Caching](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html)

[Here's a good link involving implementing an offline cache with HTML5 - it also has several good links towards the bottom.](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)

Hope this helps you out!